# In Virtuoso SPARQL query editor, ASK query returns false, why?

Tags: sparql, protege

So this is my SPARQL query and related ontology, but response is false, why? I was expecting true as Lucknow isCapitalOf UP, so there is at least one City which isCapitalOf UP.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: `isCapitalOf` is an object property, whereas `'Uttar_Pradesh'` is a literal. Should  be `ASK { ?city base:isCapitalOf base:Uttar_Pradesh }`, I guess.

Comment: Tried your solution (still false), though without base: syntax error would have been reported and not "false" as query response.

Answer (score 0):

ASK query can be better understood the query below. This query can be run successfully against any SPARQL engine.

```
ASK{
SELECT * Where {?state base:capital city:Lucknow }
}
```

If the select statement returns non empty result set, ASK query returns true. And if the select statement returns empty result set, ASK query returns false.

It helps to first write a SELECT query that returns some response.

Comment: PREFIX base: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2014/4/areasOntology>
    
   ASK{
SELECT * Where {?City base:isCapitalOf base:UP }
}Tried this too, still the same response (i.e. false)

Comment: Your problem could be that you may not be using the right prefixes. When you run this query  SELECT * Where {?City base:isCapitalOf ?State }, you would find correct IRI for both city and state. Substitute both those values into the ASK query.

Comment: tried                                                                                                                               PREFIX base: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2014/4/areasOntology>

 SELECT * Where {?City base:isCapitalOf ?State }                                                                           the output is City State :/